# Can't put CTE result to temporary table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I got a SP where I need to put CTE result to a temporary table so I can use the temporary table later on in SP. Since I am new so I am experiencing difficulty. Please help me out.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable1 (
    tmp_id              INT         NULL,
    tmp_parent_id       INT         NULL,
    temp_level          VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    temp_order          VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    temp_promoter_ID    INT         NULL
);    

DECLARE @promoterid INT = (
    SELECT
        p.promoterid
    FROM dbo.Promoters p
    INNER JOIN dbo.UserProfile u
        ON u.UserId = p.UserProfileId
    WHERE u.UserName = @Username
);

;WITH Empl_Tab (Id, ParentId, LEVEL, [Order], promoterid) AS (
    SELECT
        promoters.UserProfileId AS ID,
        promoters.Level1 AS ParentID,
        0 AS LEVEL,
        CONVERT([VARCHAR](MAX), promoters.PromoterId) AS [Order],
        promoters.PromoterId
    FROM promoters
    WHERE Promoters.PromoterId = @promoterid
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        p.UserProfileId AS ID,
        p.Level1 AS ParentID,
        Empl_Tab.LEVEL + 1 AS LEVEL,
        Empl_Tab.[Order] + CONVERT([VARCHAR](30), p.PromoterId) AS [Order],
        p.PromoterId
    FROM Promoters p
    INNER JOIN Empl_Tab
        --inner join dbo.UserProfile u on u.UserId= Promoters.UserProfileId
        ON Empl_Tab.promoterid = p.Level1
    --where p.Active!=2
)
--select Id, ParentId, LEVEL,[Order],promoterid from Empl_Tab

INSERT INTO #TempTable1     --(tmp_id, tmp_parent_id, temp_level, temp_order, temp_promoter_ID )
    SELECT *
    FROM Empl_Tab;
```

Now I like to put the `Emp1_Tab` result to the temporary table and like to use the temporary table data later on in this same SP.

Comment: What's the problem here? Any error messages?

Comment: First of all, i don't know, is the Emp1_Tab data is assigned to temporary table  or not. 2nd when i am running the total sp, it is giving error "Msg 8152, Level 16, State 10, Procedure TeamCustomersListNew, Line 42
String or binary data would be truncated."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Procedure TeamCustomersListNew, Line 42 String or binary data would be truncated.

The above error message states that one of the values you're inserting exceeds the max length. The `temp_order` column of the temp table only allows for `50` characters. You may want to increase it or use `VARCHAR(MAX)` instead:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable1 (
    tmp_id              INT          NULL,
    tmp_parent_id       INT          NULL,
    temp_level          INT          NULL,
    temp_order          VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    temp_promoter_ID    INT          NULL
);
```

Additionally, `temp_level` should be `INT`.